# Как внедрить JS код из файла-плагина на php только на странице записей, а не на всех, как сейчас?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, плагин

Сделал блог на Wordpress, поставил плагин, который выводит рейтинг статьи посредством звёзд [WP-PostRatings](https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/wp-postratings.1.83.2.zip)

В файле `wp-postratings.php` есть такой код:

```
### Function: Enqueue Ratings JavaScripts/CSS
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ratings_scripts');
function ratings_scripts() {
    $postratings_max = intval(get_option('postratings_max'));
    $postratings_custom = intval(get_option('postratings_customrating'));
    $postratings_ajax_style = get_option('postratings_ajax_style');
    $postratings_javascript = '';
    if($postratings_custom) {
        for($i = 1; $i <= $postratings_max; $i++) {
            $postratings_javascript .= 'var ratings_'.$i.'_mouseover_image=new Image();ratings_'.$i.'_mouseover_image.src=ratingsL10n.plugin_url+"/images/"+ratingsL10n.image+"/rating_'.$i.'_over."+ratingsL10n.image_ext;';
        }
    } else {
        $postratings_javascript = 'var ratings_mouseover_image=new Image();ratings_mouseover_image.src=ratingsL10n.plugin_url+"/images/"+ratingsL10n.image+"/rating_over."+ratingsL10n.image_ext;';
    }
    wp_enqueue_script('wp-postratings', plugins_url('wp-postratings/postratings-js.js'), array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_localize_script('wp-postratings', 'ratingsL10n', array(
        'plugin_url' => plugins_url('wp-postratings'),
        'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'text_wait' => __('Please rate only 1 post at a time.', 'wp-postratings'),
        'image' => get_option('postratings_image'),
        'image_ext' => RATINGS_IMG_EXT,
        'max' => $postratings_max,
        'show_loading' => intval($postratings_ajax_style['loading']),
        'show_fading' => intval($postratings_ajax_style['fading']),
        'custom' => $postratings_custom,
        'l10n_print_after' => $postratings_javascript
    ));
}
```

**Этот код внедряет в тело ВСЕХ страниц (на главной странице, в категориях, на 404 странице да и вообще везде) следующий код:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var ratingsL10n = {"plugin_url":"https:\/\/site.com\/wp-content\/plugins\/wp-postratings","ajax_url":"https:\/\/site.com\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","text_wait":"\u041f\u043e\u0436\u0430\u043b\u0443\u0439\u0441\u0442\u0430, \u043d\u0435 \u0433\u043e\u043b\u043e\u0441\u0443\u0439\u0442\u0435 \u0437\u0430 \u043d\u0435\u0441\u043a\u043e\u043b\u044c\u043a\u043e \u0437\u0430\u043f\u0438\u0441\u0435\u0439 \u043e\u0434\u043d\u043e\u0432\u0440\u0435\u043c\u0435\u043d\u043d\u043e.","image":"stars_flat(png)","image_ext":"png","max":"5","show_loading":"0","show_fading":"0","custom":"0"};
var ratings_mouseover_image=new Image();ratings_mouseover_image.src=ratingsL10n.plugin_url+"/images/"+ratingsL10n.image+"/rating_over."+ratingsL10n.image_ext;;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://site.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-postratings/postratings-js.js'></script>
```

Но он совершенно не нужен на **ВСЕХ** страницах, а нужен только на страницах записей. Потому что звёздочки подключены **ТОЛЬКО** там.

Я так думаю что надо обернуть какую то часть кодом `is_single`, но не будучи программистом мне не справится :-(

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать.

**P.S.**

Хочу обратить особое внимание на то, что добавляемый на все страницы код - вспомогательный (требуется для корректной работы самих звёзд). Код же самих звёздочек выводится вставленной в шаблон командой `<?php if(function_exists('the_ratings')) { the_ratings(); } ?>` и выглядит в конечном итоге в теле страницы он таким вот образом:

```
<div id="post-ratings-121" class="post-ratings" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" data-nonce="d927a6021d"><img id="rating_121_1" src="https://site.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-postratings/images/stars_flat(png)/rating_off.png" alt="Ужасная статья" title="Ужасная статья" onmouseover="current_rating(121, 1, 'Ужасная статья');" onmouseout="ratings_off(0, 0, 0);" onclick="rate_post();" onkeypress="rate_post();" style="cursor: pointer; border: 0px;"><img id="rating_121_2" src="https://site.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-postratings/images/stars_flat(png)/rating_off.png" alt="Так себе статья" title="Так себе статья" onmouseover="current_rating(121, 2, 'Так себе статья');" onmouseout="ratings_off(0, 0, 0);" onclick="rate_post();" onkeypress="rate_post();" style="cursor: pointer; border: 0px;"><img id="rating_121_3" src="https://site.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-postratings/images/stars_flat(png)/rating_off.png" alt="Нормальная статья" title="Нормальная статья" onmouseover="current_rating(121, 3, 'Нормальная статья');" onmouseout="ratings_off(0, 0, 0);" onclick="rate_post();" onkeypress="rate_post();" style="cursor: pointer; border: 0px;"><img id="rating_121_4" src="https://site.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-postratings/images/stars_flat(png)/rating_off.png" alt="Хорошая статья" title="Хорошая статья" onmouseover="current_rating(121, 4, 'Хорошая статья');" onmouseout="ratings_off(0, 0, 0);" onclick="rate_post();" onkeypress="rate_post();" style="cursor: pointer; border: 0px;"><img id="rating_121_5" src="https://site.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-postratings/images/stars_flat(png)/rating_off.png" alt="Отличная статья!" title="Отличная статья!" onmouseover="current_rating(121, 5, 'Отличная статья!');" onmouseout="ratings_off(0, 0, 0);" onclick="rate_post();" onkeypress="rate_post();" style="cursor: pointer; border: 0px;"> оцените материал<br><span class="post-ratings-text" id="ratings_121_text" style="display: none;"></span><meta itemprop="headline" content="ЗАГОЛОВОК СТАТЬИ"><meta itemprop="description" content="КОНТЕНТ СТАТЬИ (ОТРЫВОК)"><meta itemprop="datePublished" content="ДАТА СТАТЬИ"><meta itemprop="url" content="URL СТАТЬИ"></div>
```

Код самих звёзд выводится только на страницах записей, а вспомогательный код зачем то ВЕЗДЕ. Это я хочу исправить.

Comment: Не забывайте, что после обновления плагина у вас слетят эти настройки, т.к. вы редактируете непосредственно файлы плагина

Comment: Такие вещи я не забываю. Я всегда делаю бекап и помимо него ещё и веду лог изменений, что я сделал сам в коде файлов и плагинов :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить условие с проверкой на тип записей `is_singular()` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ratings_scripts');
function ratings_scripts() {

    if( ! is_singular('post') ) return false;

    $postratings_max = intval(get_option('postratings_max'));
    $postratings_custom = intval(get_option('postratings_customrating'));
    $postratings_ajax_style = get_option('postratings_ajax_style');
    $postratings_javascript = '';
    if($postratings_custom) {
        for($i = 1; $i <= $postratings_max; $i++) {
            $postratings_javascript .= 'var ratings_'.$i.'_mouseover_image=new Image();ratings_'.$i.'_mouseover_image.src=ratingsL10n.plugin_url+"/images/"+ratingsL10n.image+"/rating_'.$i.'_over."+ratingsL10n.image_ext;';
        }
    } else {
        $postratings_javascript = 'var ratings_mouseover_image=new Image();ratings_mouseover_image.src=ratingsL10n.plugin_url+"/images/"+ratingsL10n.image+"/rating_over."+ratingsL10n.image_ext;';
    }
    wp_enqueue_script('wp-postratings', plugins_url('wp-postratings/postratings-js.js'), array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_localize_script('wp-postratings', 'ratingsL10n', array(
        'plugin_url' => plugins_url('wp-postratings'),
        'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'text_wait' => __('Please rate only 1 post at a time.', 'wp-postratings'),
        'image' => get_option('postratings_image'),
        'image_ext' => RATINGS_IMG_EXT,
        'max' => $postratings_max,
        'show_loading' => intval($postratings_ajax_style['loading']),
        'show_fading' => intval($postratings_ajax_style['fading']),
        'custom' => $postratings_custom,
        'l10n_print_after' => $postratings_javascript
    ));
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, Виталий! Эта коротенькая строчка реализовывает задуманное в полном объёме :-)

Comment: Не за что. Теперь главное не обновлять плагин))